# R: order() not working as expected outside of RStudio

Tags: r

I have a character vector (consisting of randomly arranged numbers or letters) that I want to use to order a dataframe:

```
vals = as.numeric(dict$keys)
## ONE
vals = order(vals)
## TWO
dict = dict[vals,]
```

At `ONE`:

```
> vals

  [1]  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5
 [26]  6  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9 10 10
 [51] 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 14 14 15 15 15
 [76] 15 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 17 17 17 17 17 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18
[101] 18 19 19 19 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21
[126] 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 23
```

At `TWO`:

```
> vals

  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
 [19]  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
 [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
 [55]  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
 [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
 [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108
[109] 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126
[127] 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138
```

When I execute this snippet in RStudio in Windows, it orders the dataframe `dict` fine. Numbers are ordered first, then letters are at the end (this is what I want).

However, in a linux remote desktop where I execute with `> Rscript` , this snippet doesn't work and the dataframe remains how it was before these lines are executed.

Comment: I doubt `dict$keys` is a vector of class `character`. Try e.g. `x = c("2", "B", "1", "A", "C")`; `as.numeric(x)`; `as.numeric(as.factor(x))`. Perhaps your two systems have different R versions, with different `stringsAsFactors` default? Please provide a _small reproducible_ example (like e.g. `x`).

Comment: You need to show us what is in `dict` so we can reproduce.  (You should also fix the code:  `vals` wasn't changed by what you wrote.)

Comment: @Henrik - thank you, you were exactly right with the different defaults for `stringsAsFactors`.

Comment: @user2554330 - I've fixed the issue now, but where are you saying `vals` isn't being changed? It is getting modified in my scripts.

Comment: Your first line creates `vals`, the second line changes it, the third line doesn't change it.  I was probably mistaken that you thought all 3 lines changed it.  Posting the code whose output you're displaying helps avoid this kind of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by defining `stringsAsFactors = F` for all uses of `data.frame` in the script as Henrik suggested. The issue lied in the different versions of R I was using on the two systems.